# Rails securing letter_opener

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

Alright, I'm actually using [letter_opener_web](https://github.com/fgrehm/letter_opener_web) as a way to preview emails I'm about to send. Understand, I'm not on the developer side (letter_opener is originally meant for dev environment) but on the side of the user of my website. I am using letter_opener as a production component.

I need to generare an access to letter_opener views, however the default implementation of letter_opener is done in routes.rb

```
mount LetterOpenerWeb::Engine, at: "/letter_opener"
```

I have for now used a trick of generating a random path and only communicating the URL in the web views I render, however, well, it's just bad :D

```
if Rails.env.development?
  mount LetterOpenerWeb::Engine, at: "/letter_opener"
else
  mount LetterOpenerWeb::Engine, at: "/#{SecureRandom.hex(12)}"
end
```

Is there a way I can override some controller to add my own access control implementation ? My current access control (which I won't change) is done this way

```
class ApplicationController
  before_action :access_denied
end

class SomeController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_action :allow_access_to_xxxx
end
```

Which is why I need some way to override a controler of letter_opener while still making its views available (if possible by keeping the simple syntax to add in routes !)

EDIT : my user case. Only a couple lines of code to preview instead of sending an email

```
   ...
    mail(
      to: dst,
      from: message[:from],
      subject: @subject_full,
      delivery_method: real_or_preview(message))
    ...

# Switch delivery method to letter_opener if preview
    def real_or_preview(message)
      if message[:preview]
        :letter_opener
      else
        ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method
      end
    end
```

Comment: Whats the use case? Are you letting users make some kind of fancypants HTML emails which they can preview?

Comment: Yeah. I also let them use special tags, which may easily mess things up so it's a way to check they did things right.

Comment: I would be a bit hesitant deploying anything explicitly made for development in a production setting - often those gems are not up to production standards when it comes to speed and performance. I would create a really basic controller which renders the email previews and try to delegate out as much as possible to concerns and service object so that you can reuse the same code in your mailer - which also can use the same views.

Comment: Have you looked at Have you checked out letter_opener_web (https://github.com/fgrehm/letter_opener_web)? I didn't look into it that much, but it seems to do what you're asking

Comment: @max The application is small scale, users that will use the preview feature are a small subset of users, and overall the context/performance is ok for that sort of stuff, but thanks for your concern. My current implementation was extra fast : only ~10 lines of code to be able to generate previews instead of sending the real emails, I doubt I can do better.

Comment: @Vasseurth I am already using letter_opener_web. letter_opener by itself doesn't have any views and it cannot be mounted in routes.

Comment: have you considered monkeypatching the engine application controller? https://github.com/fgrehm/letter_opener_web/blob/master/app/controllers/letter_opener_web/application_controller.rb

Comment: @phoet How do I do that ? Can I do this inside an inititializer ?

Comment: @CyrilDD yes, that should work